# VBA replace all text after specific word with ""

Tags: excel, vba

I have this string of text `Part Number 1234 from workbook 2` and I want to save the string to be just `Part Number 1234` and replace everything that occurs starting at `from` and to the right to be replaced with   a space.

This is what I have tried so far. The way I have it set up now, it will replace `"bin"` with a space `""` but if I change it to `"*bin"` it will not replace anything in the string.

```
Dim module As String, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet 
module = ws.Cells(1, 2).value ' the cell value is Part Number 1234 from workbook 2 
    module = Replace(module, "bin", "")
    Debug.Print module
```

Comment: Try using InStr and Left.

Comment: @BrianMStafford would that be if `bin` is in the string then replace everything from bin to the left?

Comment: `InStr` finds "bin".  `Left` can be used to give everything from the beginning up to "bin".

Answer (score 0):

Your text states `"replace "bin" with a space ""`, but `""` is NOT a space.

If you want to replace everything from `from` and to the right with a null string, then:

```
Trim(Split(myString,deLimiter)(0))
```

or

```
Split(myString," " & deLimiter)(0)
```

If you really do want a space, then remove the `Trim` function from the first example, or the `" "` from the second.